# How to bind or execute relaycommand in Wpf from button click event in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi am using button click event in xaml file :

```
   <Button Focusable="False" Click="btnAddhighlight"
                        Grid.Column="0" Width="37" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Stretch="None">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Highlighter.png"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Highlighter_pressed.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </Button>
```

I am using button click event in  xaml.cs file :

```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
//I want to call relay command from this code

    }
```

This is my relay command :

```
        AddHighlight = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            int page = _pageNumber;
            SelectionInfo selection = _selection;

            Rect? selectedVilualInfo = null;
            if (_selection != null)
                selectedVilualInfo = ConvertPixelsToScreen(_selection.SelectedRect, CurrentZoom, _visualObject);

            ParentVM.HighlightVM.SelectedVilualInfo = selectedVilualInfo;
            ParentVM.HighlightVM.IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
            var vm = (ParentVM.CurrentReadingVm as ReadingBookSingleVM);
            if (vm != null)
            {
                ParentVM.HighlightVM.ResetCurrentColor();
                vm.SaveHighlight(page, HighlightVM.SerializeColorToString(ParentVM.HighlightVM.CurrentColor.Color));

                vm.CancelSelection(page);
                Selection = null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wrap all this Command Inside the Method and call the function from your Button click event

Comment: Get the current context of your UserControl or a window: `var vm = (<your VM type>)this.DataContext;` and then call that relayCommand `vm.AddHighlight.Execute(object param);`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var vm = (yourViewModel)DataContext;
    vm.AddHighlight.Execute(null);

 }
```

or use eventtocommand of mvvmlight toolkit,

but with controls which have command property button and checkbox for example 
you have just to bind your RelayCommand to the command property

```
<Button Focusable="False" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
```